# How to change icon at the top of software in Windows 8?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, icons

How to change icon at the top of software in Windows 8? When you open software, it has little icon at the left top. The icon show on Taskbar or Star is easy to change, but the top left is hard. Do you know the way to change it?

Comment: It does not have it always ... browsers for example have the icon on each tab ....

Comment: Can you be a little more descriptive where this icon is exactly?

Comment: That icon is branded as a resource in the executable.  You would need to use Visual Studio to modify the icon resource in the executable.

Comment: @rrirower: I'll try and inform whether it could be.